# T-SQL and/or LINQ query with multiple criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following sample many-to-many relationship:

[image]

I am building a UI to allow a user to select multiple Documents to be batched together.  Each Batch can have many Documents; each Document can only be in one Batch UNLESS the Batch has been voided.

On this UI, I need to display *available* Documents.  A Document is considered *available* if it is:

- Not void, not batched (i.e. has a record in BatchDocument to associated it to a Batch)
- Not void, batched BUT the Batch is void

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE tmpDocument (DocumentID INT, IsVoid BIT)

INSERT INTO tmpDocument VALUES (1,1)
INSERT INTO tmpDocument VALUES (2,0)
INSERT INTO tmpDocument VALUES (3,0)
INSERT INTO tmpDocument VALUES (4,0)
INSERT INTO tmpDocument VALUES (5,0)
INSERT INTO tmpDocument VALUES (6,0)
INSERT INTO tmpDocument VALUES (7,0)
INSERT INTO tmpDocument VALUES (8,0)
INSERT INTO tmpDocument VALUES (9,0)

CREATE TABLE tmpBatch (BatchID INT, IsVoid BIT)

INSERT INTO tmpBatch VALUES (1,0)
INSERT INTO tmpBatch VALUES (2,1)
INSERT INTO tmpBatch VALUES (3,0)

CREATE TABLE tmpBatchDocument (BatchDocumentID INT, BatchID INT, DocumentID INT)

INSERT INTO tmpBatchDocument VALUES (1,1,2)
INSERT INTO tmpBatchDocument VALUES (2,1,3)
INSERT INTO tmpBatchDocument VALUES (3,2,4)
INSERT INTO tmpBatchDocument VALUES (4,2,5)
INSERT INTO tmpBatchDocument VALUES (5,3,6)
INSERT INTO tmpBatchDocument VALUES (6,3,7)
INSERT INTO tmpBatchDocument VALUES (7,3,8)
```

**Document**

```
DocumentID---IsVoid
1------------1-----
2------------0-----
3------------0-----
4------------0-----
5------------0-----
6------------0-----
7------------0-----
8------------0-----
9------------0-----
```

**Batch**

```
BatchID------IsVoid
1------------0-----
2------------1-----
3------------0-----
```

**BatchDocument**

```
BatchDocumentID-----BatchID------DocumentID
1-------------------1------------2---------
2-------------------1------------3---------
3-------------------2------------4---------
4-------------------2------------5---------
5-------------------3------------6---------
6-------------------3------------7---------
7-------------------3------------8---------
```

To find *available* Documents, I came up with this T-SQL query:

```
SELECT a.DocumentID
FROM tmpDocument a
LEFT JOIN tmpBatchDocument b ON a.DocumentID = b.DocumentID
LEFT JOIN tmpBatch c ON b.BatchID = c.BatchID
WHERE (
        b.DocumentID IS NULL
        AND a.IsVoid = 0
        )
    OR (c.IsVoid = 1)
```

The query correctly returns:

```
DocumentID
4
5
9
```

Document 1 is excluded because it is voided; Documents 2, 3, 6, 7, and 8 are excluded because they are batched and the Batch is not voided; Documents 4 and 5 are included because although they are batched, the Batch has been voided; Document 9 is included because it is not voided and it is not batched

Now, let's say I select Documents 4 and 5 and add them to a new Batch.

```
BatchID------IsVoid
1------------0-----
2------------1-----
3------------0-----
4------------0-----

BatchDocumentID-----BatchID------DocumentID
1-------------------1------------2---------
2-------------------1------------3---------
3-------------------2------------4---------
4-------------------2------------5---------
5-------------------3------------6---------
6-------------------3------------7---------
7-------------------3------------8---------  
8-------------------4------------4---------
9-------------------4------------5---------
```

Running the same query returns the same results:

```
DocumentID
4
5
9
```

Since Documents 4 and 5 are now associated to a non-voided Batch, I expected they would be excluded from the results and only Document 9 would be shown.  Clearly, that did not happen.

How can I rewrite this query to show Documents that are only associated to a voided batch, but exclude them if they are also associated to a non-voided Batch?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @FelixPamittan Woah!  Sorry about that.  The submit timed out and I had to refresh the page.  I didn't notice that the end of my question was missing when I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `COUNT` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT d.DocumentID
FROM tmpDocument d
LEFT JOIN tmpBatchDocument bd 
    ON bd.DocumentID = d.DocumentID
LEFT JOIN tmpBatch b
    ON b.BatchID = bd.BatchID
WHERE
    d.IsVoid = 0
GROUP BY d.DocumentID
HAVING 
    COUNT(bd.BatchDocumentID) = 0
    OR COUNT(CASE WHEN b.IsVoid = 0 THEN 1 END) = 0
```

The `WHERE` clause will obviously exclude voided documents. The first condition in the `HAVING` clause searches for documents that are not batched and the second condition will search for documents that are batch but the batch is voided.

[Try it here.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/437773)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.DocumentID
FROM tmpDocument a
LEFT JOIN tmpBatchDocument b ON a.DocumentID = b.DocumentID
LEFT JOIN tmpBatch c ON b.BatchID = c.BatchID
WHERE (
        b.DocumentID IS NULL
        AND a.IsVoid = 0 --WHY?  
        )
    OR (c.IsVoid = 1
        AND NOT EXISTS (select * from c2 where c2.batchID = (select batchID from b2 where b2.DocumentID=a.documentID) AND c2.isVoid=0)
)
```

Edited answer to include the NOT EXISTS. Having now read your full question, that's what I think you need in order to exclude those records where there is a non-void batch associated to the document.

Comment: Without that criteria, Document 1, which is voided, will show up.

Comment: got it, it's checking the document's isvoid property, not the batch.